# How do I use a .svg image as a HTML icon?

Tags: html, css, svg, icons

I have some .svg images and I want to use then as icon in my webpage. Is there any way to do this with the `<i>` tag?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at [ask] and post a [mre] of your code so we can see what you've attempted and better assist you in reaching your desired outcome! :)

Comment: The answer is `yes`. In a nut-shell, an SVG could be either used inline (e.g. direct child of an HTML element) or as an external asset (e.g. using an `img` tag). There are several approaches to practical implementation (e.g. using multiple `def`s in a single `svg` element/file, loading individual files, etc). Without a code example that shows what your intention is and how it's being implemented, this question is too open-ended and cannot be fully answered other than `yes, there is a way`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem adding the svg code of the image directly on my html.

Something like this:

```html
<svg class="bi bi-x-circle" fill="#ec5e45" height="16"
     viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path
        d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
    <path
        d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
</svg>
```